# JQuery isn't parsing JSON response properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery fullcalendar plugin , I have tried altering this many different ways from answers to other questions with no luck, here is my jQuery:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,

        aspectRatio: 3,
        height: 1000,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: function (start, end, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetEvents",
                data: "{'userID':" + "'B473795D-306A-4718-804B-2813884D5B48'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(doc.d);
                   var res = unescape(obj);
                    $(res).find('event').each(function () {
                        events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                        });
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my response :

```
  {"d":"[{ \"title\"  : \"circleJerk\", \"start\"  : \"2012-06-22\" }, { \"title\"  : \"BangTheWife\", \"start\"  : \"2012-06-15\" , \"end\" : \"2012-06-23\" } ]"}
```

Comment: what is `unescape` for. I dont think you need it

Comment: I tried without it, just because of  \"

Comment: then dont you think you should use it before parsejason

Comment: How is your response generated? Seems to me if you fix it so you don't try to embed JSON strings within JSON strings then you wouldn't need to do any parsing (beyond what `$.ajax()` does for you automatically). Having said that, your use of `unescape` is wrong: you can't `unescape` an object. You could try `obj=$.parseJSON(unescape(doc.d))` so that you actually `unescape` the string _before_ parsing it but in any case (as CoDe aDDict suggested) I don't think `unescape` is the right function in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return type from your method `GetEvents` is `string` isn't it?

Try returning a `List<Event>` (or whatever your object is called) and then you don't need to go through the mess of unescaping a JSON string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetEvents", //return type List<Event>
    data: "{'userID':" + "'B473795D-306A-4718-804B-2813884D5B48'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (doc) {
        //doc.d = [Event,Event,Event] (no processing needed)
        callback(events);
    }
});
```

In response to your comment, a method with return type of List<> will look like :

```
[{"title": "sometitle", "start": "yourData"},{"title":"someTitle2", "start":"yourStart2"}]
```

Translating ASP.NET ASMX webmethod `DateTime` serialization to JavaScript `Date` object:

```
DateFromASPNET = function (sNetDate) {
    if (sNetDate == null) return;
    var r = /\/Date\(([0-9]+)\)\//i
    var matches = sNetDate.match(r);
    if (matches.length == 2) {
        return new Date(parseInt(matches[1]));
    }
    else {
        return sNetDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that going to change JSON to { "event" : { "title" : ".." , "start" : ".." } "event" { ...

Comment: One "gotcha" to ASMX web services when you're serializing dates is ASP returns a DateTime property as a wonderfully nonstandard `/Date(UNIXTIMESTAMP)/` format. So if your `start` property is of `DateTime`, you will need to "fix" that client-side before doing anything with it. I'll include my 'translation' function in my answer above

Comment: I'm not using .asmx - I'm using  url: "Default.aspx/GetEvents", which is a WebMethod , and it is returning List<Event> which only has the 2 required properities of title, and start , response now looks like this   --

Comment: {"d":[{"__type":"Event","Title":"circle jerk","Start":"2012-06-22","title":"circle jerk","start":"2012-06-22"},{"__type":"Event","

Comment: Scott, WebMethods (should) act the same regardless of ASMX/ASPX. you can still use Date.parse() on your `start` property if you need to do formatting or other "math" against your start date. Regardless, it looks like you've got some nice clean output for your JS to consume now

Comment: except Title is capitolized in the firse event , and lower in teh second - that's weird c# did that on its own when it automatically goes through javascript serializer

Comment: oh, very weird, I didn't notice that at first glance. Never seen anything like that before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AJAX is aysnchronous so by passing a function to `events` option, nothing is returned due to the AJAX call.

Use the built in AJX methods of the plugin by simply passing a ajax options to  `eventsources` option.

From Docs:  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
        url: "Default.aspx/GetEvents",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        data: "{'userID':" + "'B473795D-306A-4718-804B-2813884D5B48'}"
    }

 ]
});
```

EDIT: can also pass single event source ajax options object to `events` option per docs