# Getting data from ASP.Net JSON service with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call the Google Maps geocoding API, to get a formatted address from a lat/long pair, and then log it to the console. I am trying to get the first 'formatted_address' item that gets returned for a given location. 
I am simple unable to extract that item from the JSON, I have no idea why. The line of code needed to extract the data would be greatly appreciated.

The javascript:

```
//Gets the current location of the user
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }

}

function showPosition(position)
{
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ReportIncident.aspx/ReverseGeocode",
        data: "{latitude:" + latitude + ",longitude:" + longitude + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (returnedData)
        {
         // console.log(/****formatted_address Here Please****/);
        }
    });
}
```

The C#:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string ReverseGeocode(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
        {
            // Create the web request  

            string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude +
                         "&sensor=true";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            // Get response  
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                // Get the response stream  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                // Console application output  
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am myself not sure about it, but are you sure you should be using **POST**?

Comment: @John, the data gets returned alright, I just can't extract it.

Comment: @lee can you show us the JSON string being returned, please?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it is the same as the data from http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true, but it is wrapped in the "d" element, as is standard with the above type of web service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166355/jquery-isnt-parsing-json-response-properly/11166409#11166409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is escaped because you're returning a string from your `WebMethod`, and not letting the built in `JavascriptSerializer` do it's thing.

roughly, you're seeing this:

```
"\{ /*data*/ \}"
```

instead of this:

```
{ /*data*/ }
```

You can fix this by running the returned string through `eval()` but note that I'm not recommending it... just saying *you can*

**EDIT**:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ReportIncident.aspx/ReverseGeocode",
    data: "{latitude:" + latitude + ",longitude:" + longitude + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (returnedData)
    {
        var realReturnedData = eval(returnedData.d);
        //realReturnedData now has the google maps data structure you're expecting
    }
});
```

Again... *eval is evil* (if you don't 100% trust the source). I would recommend returning a different data type from your webmethod...

**EDIT 2**:

```
[WebMethod]
public static MyClass ReverseGeocode(decimal lat, decimal long) {
   MyClass obj = new MyClass();
   //do stuff
   return obj;
}
```

But my real question is why are you doing this with a webservice call to your server? You can directly do geocoding from Javascript to google's API https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Comment: I think you are right, but how do I let the built-in javascript serializer do its thing.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using eval if you trust the source.

Comment: @rossisdead: True enough. I haven't found a case where it's been necessary, though in my line of work. The point is to refactor and not use it if possible. Given the automatic serialization ASMX/ASPX webmethods offer, it certainly isn't necessary here if using a complex (user-defined) return type (which would also open that method up to being useful for other parts of the server-side code).

Comment: @BLSully thanks, I used the javascript API, and that solved everything. The returning a string and not use the javascript serializer was also 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the API returns something like:

```
{
    "results" : [
    {
        "address_components" : [/***/],
        "formatted_address": "..."
        /* other */
    }],
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

You could try:

```
if(returnedData.results.length > 0) {
    console.log(returnedData.results[0].formatted_address);
}
```

EDIT: Take a look at the API documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: I keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, even though data is being returned.

Comment: @lee: Now am beginning to wonder if you are actually receiving the EXPECTED data

Comment: I am getting the correct data: it is returning my address, I just cannot get it from the JSON.